# Running add-VpnConnection powershell returns invalid namespace

Tags: windows-10, vpn, powershell

To get around a bug in Windows 10 where the authentication information is reverted from Username & password to General Authentication, I am trying to run the powershell command "add-VpnConnection".

After attempted execution, the error "Set-VpnConnectionIPsecConfiguration : Invalid namespace" is returned.

Please could someone point out the error of my ways or advise how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post the full command you are using?

Comment: Post the command your typing.

Answer (score 0):

Would put this in an edit but unable to edit the post.

The powershell command I used was the following:

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name "WG IKEv2" -ServerAddress "x.x.x.x" -TunnelType "Ikev2" -AuthenticationMethod "Eap" -EncryptionLevel "Maximum"
```

However, further research suggested a possible bug in Windows 10 relating to the set up of VPNs. We were able to replicate on multiple Win 10 Pro machines.

Essentially, when one attempts to set up an IKEv2 VPN using the GUI/Wizard, if "Username & Password" is selected for authentication, it is not always saved. On return to the wizard, the authentication method reverts to "General Authentication". To fix this, weirdly, we went to the VPN adaptor properties, navigated through tabs, closed the properties, returned to the VPN wizard and authentication info can now be saved.